# Roll Up Summary Tasks based on text input

Tags: vba, ms-project

I am trying to set up a quick roll up macro. I have a large project file 2000 lines with a repeated summary tasks called Contract Award Dates as one of the main summary headings. However its not needed to be viewed often
See example Project file below.

[image]

I have attempted to roll up the Summary tasks by prompting the Summary task name to roll up and code below but it returns a mismatch error

```
   'Roll up Summary Tasks based on Input'

Sub RollUpTasks()

    Dim txt As String
    txt = InputBox("Flag tasks that include the following text in their names:")

    Dim tsk As Task
    Set Proj = ActiveProject

    For Each tsk In Proj.Tasks
    'If task is summary and matchs input txt, set its rollup property to True'
    If tsk.Summary And tsk.Name = InStr(1, tsk.Name, txt, 1) Then
    tsk.Rollup = True
    ' If task isn't a summary task set its Rollup property to False'
    Else
    tsk.Rollup = False
    End If
    Next tsk

End Sub
```

[image]

Seems to be an issue with this If Statement I set up 
[image]

Comment: Since the [Rollup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.task.rollup) field is a Boolean field just like the Flag fields, this is a duplicate of [How to Set Flag field to Yes or No Based on Text input - Microsoft-Project-VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58634897/how-to-set-flag-field-to-yes-or-no-based-on-text-input-microsoft-project-vba). The error is due to the fact that `Instr` returns an integer, not text.

Comment: `If tsk.Summary And InStr(1, tsk.Name, txt, 1)>0 Then`